# Retrieve Google+ activities returns 403, "Access Not Configured" in Android, using GoogleIO13 sample app code

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services, googleio

I am tryng to use the Google IO 2013 code sample, specifically the SocialStreamFragment to display google plus post based on a hashtag search.

Steps done:

1. Integrated SocialStreamFragment.java class and associated clasees, etc, in my project.
2. In the Console API , I have enabled Google+ API for my project
3. In the Console API I generated a Simple API Access key for Android Apps, configuring my app's package and debug/prod keys as allowed app.
4. I copied the Simple Access Key as Config.API_KEY.

However the code below to get the Activities/Posts fails with IOException : 403, "Access Not Configured".

```
      public List<Activity> loadInBackground() {
            mIsLoading = true;

            // Set up the HTTP transport and JSON factory
            HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = new GsonFactory();

            // Set up the main Google+ class
            Plus plus = new Plus.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
                    .setApplicationName(NetUtils.getUserAgent(getContext()))
                    .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(
                            new CommonGoogleClientRequestInitializer(Config.API_KEY))
                    .build();

            ActivityFeed activities = null;
            try {
                activities = plus.activities().search(mSearchString)
                        .setPageToken(mNextPageToken)
                        .setOrderBy("recent")
                        .setMaxResults(MAX_RESULTS_PER_REQUEST)
                        .setFields(PLUS_RESULT_FIELDS)
                        .execute();

                mHasError = false;
                mNextPageToken = activities.getNextPageToken();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                mHasError = true;
                mNextPageToken = null;The 
            }

            return (activities != null) ? activities.getItems() : null;
        }
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

My project has also in API Console configured Client IDs for installed applications. Can this be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the Google+ API enabled in the API console?

[image: Screenshot from the console]